# how to set the drawable paint color with background in android?

Tags: android, android-drawable, alpha-transparency

there is the snippet of my layout file:
`layout_1` with backgound `#e9e9e9`

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:background="#e9e9e9"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    ...
    <com.test.android.CustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    ...
</LinerLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    ...
    <com.test.android.CustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    ...
</LinerLayout>
```

There is my custom drawable and CustomView classes snippets. The top one partly cover the bottom one.

```
public class NodeDrawable extends Drawable {

  //...

  protected ShapeDrawable shapeDrawableBottom;
  protected ShapeDrawable shapeDrawableTop;

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
          Paint circlePaint = shapeDrawableBottom.getPaint();
          circlePaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR_BOTTOM);//DEFAULT_COLOR_BOTTOM = 0xe2f5ff
          circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
          shapeDrawableBottom.setBounds();
          shapeDrawableBottom.draw(canvas);

          Paint circlePaint = shapeDrawableTop.getPaint();
          circlePaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR_TOP);//DEFAULT_COLOR_TOP = 0x1f8fd2
          circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
          shapeDrawableBottom.setBounds();
          shapeDrawableTop.draw(canvas);
  }

  //...
}


public class CustomView extends View {

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        buildDrawables();
    }

    private void buildDrawables() {
        mCustomDrawable = new CustomDrawable();
    }

}
```

But the layout background have an effect on the bottom one and the bottom one effect the top one either.

How can i ensure them displayed in correct RGB color, what i should do with the RGBA's alpha value?
I have tried set the color to 0xe2f5ff with alpha value 1, but  i think the layout backgound still have an effect on the bottom color...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
circlePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
```

where first 2 digit is for Alpha. 00 to FF